# Angular 2 - Toggle class only on single element

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a list of elements which looks like :

```
 <ul *ngFor="let period of periodsDate">
        <li                         
        [class.show]="isShown" (click)="toggleClass()">
        <a>{{ period.id }} </a>
        </li>
</ul>
```

I add/remove the 'show' class by using the following method:

```
toggleClass() {
        this.isShown = !this.isShown;
    }
```

The problem I have is that since there are multiple `<li>` elements, every time I click on any of them the 'show' class is added to all of them. 
What I want to achieve is that the class 'show' is only added to the `<li>` element that was just clicked.

Comment: `period.isShown = !period.isShown`  (passing period as an argument into toggleClass)

Answer (score 0):

Use with object `period`, do not create another object
try below code

```
<ul *ngFor="let period of periodsDate">
    <li class="dropdown__nested" [class.show]="period.isShown" (click)="toggleClass(period)">
        <a>{{ period.key }} </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Typscript

```
toggleClass(period) {
    period.isShown = !period.isShown;
}
```

Comment: This works but why would I need to extend period? It seems redundant

Comment: did you create class for `period`? if yes, you can add `isShown:boolean` in that class.

Comment: @greatTeacherOnizuka: because you're in a for loop, the toccleClass function argument **has to be something**, else how can you guess which of the periodsDates you have to change? there are two ways to handle this: 1) the way Sanjay provided: use a toggleClass function, pass to it the reference to an element and toggle a property. 2) extend the "period" object by adding a function that toggles the isShown variable. Both are good, but the second one, to me, is cleaner. Beware: the `this` in your toggleClass() function is NOT the this you are expecting.